# Nextjs pass id but don't display in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to pass product id from category to product page without displaying on `url`

**Category.js**

```
<h2>
  <Link href={{
      pathname: `/product/car/${title}`,
      query: {
          id: Item.id,
      },
  }} as={`/product/car/${(Item.description}`}>{Item.description}</Link>
</h2>
```

**[...slug].js**

```
function slug(context) {
    const Router = useRouter()
    const { slug } = Router.query;
    console.log(slug)
    console.log(context.params);
// want to get id here
    return (
        <div className="container">
            hello {slug}
        </div>
    )
}

export default slug;
```

**Result:**

What I trying to achieve is get id from category page link, if I do this `/product/car/1/bmw` I able to get id but I want this url `/product/car/bmw` but also get id, is there anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way?

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

const C = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.router.query)
  }, [props.router])
}

export default withRouter(C);
```

Answer (score 0):

May this code works for you!

Import route like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
```

Define route like this:

```
const router = useRouter();
```

Change route like this:

```
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        router.push({
          pathname: `/product/car/${Item.description}`,
          query: { id: Item.id },
        })
      }}
    >
        {Item.description}
    </button>
```

Comment: this will result like this: `/product/car/bmw?id=1`

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to use Slug only don't put the ID into the query string!

```
<h2>
  <Link href={{
      pathname: `/product/car/${title}`,
  }} as={`/product/car/${(Item.description}`}>{Item.description}</Link>
</h2>
```

Then you need to search the ID based on the Slug where you want to get the id. I don't know the structure of your Item but if you have Items in an array you should search for specific item based on slug like this:

```
const items = [
  {'id': 1, 'slug': 'mercedes'},
  {'id': 2, 'slug': 'ford'},
  {'id': 3, 'slug': 'bmw'}
];
const slugToFind = 'bmw';

var result = items.find(x => x.slug === slugToFind);
console.log(result.id);
```